# Socket.io array access

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a simple app using socket.io and node.js and I have started to think about access to array from different events. So when somebody is joining to room I am pushing him to an array of all clients. Then I am looking for a specific client in an array to change some of his attributes. Finally when client disconnects I am removing him from array. Is there a chance that after function finds index of a specific client that client disconnects and the wrong client attribute will be changed?
Here is piece of code

```
let array=[];

io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('join',function(data){
    array.push(client);
  });
  client.on('message',function(data){
    let index= findOtherClientIndexInArray();
    if(index>-1){
        //If client leaves the array is altered so the index is not pointing at correct client
        array[index].attribute++;
    }
  });
  client.on('leave',function(data){
    array.splice(array.indexOf(client),1)
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong client attribute will be changed"? Are you asking if a wrong client could be removed? Node.js being single-threaded should take care of what you're worried about either way, I belive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no risk of `index` no longer referring to the intended client in the array within a block of synchronous code, since Node.js is a single-threaded environment.

However, if I could make a suggestion for improving your maintainability a little, you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array:

```
let set = new Set();

io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('join', function (data) {
    set.add(client);
  });

  client.on('message', function (data) {
    // return client directly instead of a key or index
    // return undefined or null if none is found
    let other = findOtherClientInSet();

    if (other) {
      other.attribute++;
    }
  });

  client.on('leave', function (data) {
    set.delete(client);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for suggesting using sets